# How to get a certain elements inside an array inside a jsonObject

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, filereader, json-simple

I'm exporting some data in java using JSON then I'm reading that data and trying to get elements from an array inside the JSON object but I'm having issues.

I have tried a lot of things like

```
jsonObject.get("InGameCord").get("x")
Object Testo = jsonObject.get("InGameCord");
Testo.x
```

Things like that along with more that did not work so deleted the code.

This is the exported JSON file and im trying to access the InGameCord array X or Y.

```
{"BaseID":1,"BaseName":"Bandar-e-Jask Airbase","InGameCord":[{"x":463,"y":451}]}
```

Here is my file reader code

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
System.out.println(jsonObject);
System.out.println("BaseName: "+jsonObject.get("BaseName"));
System.out.println("BaseID: "+jsonObject.get("BaseID"));
System.out.println("InGameCord: "+jsonObject.get("InGameCord"));
```

All of this works and exports the correct info.

So I'm trying to get let us say the X value of InGameCord.

```
int X = 463;
```

Comment: Where are you getting **JSON**Object and **JSON**Parser from? I ask because the Java EE 8 specification uses different case for the interface names: `javax.json.JsonObject` and `javax.json.stream.JsonParser`.

Comment: ```import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your JSON data `{"BaseID":1,"BaseName":"Bandar-e-Jask Airbase","InGameCord":[{"x":463,"y":451}]}`:

- `"InGameCord"` is the name of an array which can be instantiated as a `JSONArray`.
- That array contains only one element: `{"x":463,"y":451}`.
- That array element can be instantiated as a `JSONObject`. It contains two name/value pairs:

  - `"x"` with the value 463.
  - `"y"` with the value 451.

So based on the code you provided, to instantiate the `JSONArray`:

`JSONArray numbers = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("InGameCord");`

To retrieve the first (and only) element of the array into a `JSONObject`:

`JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) numbers.get(0);`

To get the value for "x" into an `int` variable cast the `Object` returned by `get()` to a `Number`, and then get its `intValue()`:

`int value = ((Number) jObj.get("x")).intValue();`

You can even do the whole thing in one line, but it's ugly:

`int y = ((Number) ((JSONObject) numbers.get(0)).get("y")).intValue();`